# Ffmpeg interpeting conversion error messages

Tags: ffmpeg, conversion, error-logging

I am trying to decipher the quality of converted videos by inspecting the error output log(s).  The log is created by `-loglevel error` .  The video source is from OTA .ts recordings, and the problem is from signal strength.  I could say the quality is that "the video has errors" because those outputs are triggered.  Some recordings are better than others though: some with slight artifacts, many artifacts, a/v gets unsynced etc...

I want to filter and count error types to make degrees of judgement of, say, Excellent, Good or Corrupt.

Here is a very bad log containing typical errors.
https://pastebin.com/ZajZW5WB

Which ones mean what i.e. severity?

Currently, I only estimate the quality by ranges of error line count.

Edit: Here is the ffmpeg line used via PowerShell:

```
C:\Users\User\Documents\Computer\FfMPEG\bin\ffmpeg -loglevel error -hide_banner -nostats -y -itsoffset 0.2 -i $videofile.Name -i $videofile.Name -map 0:0 -map 1:1 -vf yadif -c:v:0 libx264 -ar 44100 -scodec copy $newmp4filename 2> C:\Users\User\Documents\Computer\FfMPEG\ffreport.txt
```

Line summary: command starts, "error" loglevel, same file loaded for offsetting video, deinterlacing filter, video converted with h264, audio rate 44100 kHz, copy subtitles, PS error output stream to file.

Comment: I think you need to edit and show the ffmpeg command you are using. Based on a quick Google of the error, you might be passing the wrong thing to one of the parameters perhaos, but that's based on only the error log top part and kind of guessing. I got something related to incompatible fps rates too, but another guess only too.

Comment: Line added above.

Comment: "Error log top part": Yes, I began trying to solving this at https://superuser.com/q/1749943/1734749 I'm not sure if it's the command launch or PS error output handling.

Comment: I would try to work it out using [start-process](https://ss64.com/ps/start-process.html) and play with the `-RedirectStandardOutput` or `-RedirectStandardError` parameters.  So for example in PowerShell run `Start-Process "C:\Users\User\Documents\Computer\FfMPEG\bin\ffmpeg.exe" -ArgumentList '-loglevel error -hide_banner -nostats -y -itsoffset 0.2 -i $videofile.Name -i $videofile.Name -map 0:0 -map 1:1 -vf yadif -c:v:0 libx264 -ar 44100 -scodec copy $newmp4filename' -RedirectStandardError "C:\Users\User\Documents\Computer\FfMPEG\ffreport.txt"`

Comment: Also, I like working out PowerShell logic in PowerShell_ISE.exe and then once I get the kinks ironed out there, I then move it over to Powershell.exe executing as a script, etc.

Comment: Been trying it.  The error output is much better but getting other problems.  Had to use double quotes for -Args and no .name operation, but strange problems.  Getting messages from SuperUser about Comments - need to move to Chat.  Have to pause on this for now.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/140234/discussion-between-louf-and-vomit-it-chunky-mess-style).